# How to bypass pdf online checks?

Tags: security, pdf

I was wondering if it is possibile to bypass a pdf online check (there is inside it a customized, hence I’m recognizable, crypted data in it that’s sent in a server to check either I view the pdf or not) by for example capturing screenshots page by page (maybe some program can do it automatically?) or if the only solution is to don’t turn internet on before and in the meanwhile I’m viewing it. I hope it is clear, thanks in advance!

Comment: You appear to have received a pdf with some kind of DRM. If you don't want to be subject to the conditions of this DRM, you shouldn't use that document, at least not in its current form.

Comment: In this case I’m not violating any DRM, it’s just for aknowledge purposes only (I may don’t want to be tracked)